# Best way to share Eclipse Android Project to mulitple Workspaces

Tags: android, eclipse, workspace

I've some Eclipse  project that are Library and I want to share these projects and source code beetween many Eclipse workspaces that contain other Android projects. What's the best approach to organize project folder, workspaces and shared libraries?

Comment: Gradle projects are pretty easy to share, but last time I used Eclipse it didn't have as good of Gradle support as Android Studio

Comment: Ok, so your are sayng that the best way is to  leave  Eclipse and migrate all projects to Android Studio?

Comment: I mean, Eclipse is no longer supported by the Android Development team, so probably, yes. Otherwise, you could use the Eclipse classpath settings to include libraries as dependencies.